# file_get_contents not returning entire site

Tags: php, wordpress, file-get-contents

I have been trying to retrieve the contents of a website (https://www.programsgulf.com/) using file_get_contents. Unfortunately, the resulting output is missing many elements (images, formating, styling, etc...), and just basically looks nothing like the original page I'm trying to retrieve.

This has never happened before with any other URLs I have tried retrieve using this same method, but for some reason, this particular URL (https://www.programsgulf.com/) refuses to work properly.

The code I'm using is:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.programsgulf.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Am I missing anything? All suggestions on how to get this working properly would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all for your time and consideration.

Comment: What you're looking for is a spiderbot. For instance: https://github.com/mvdbos/php-spider but there are many others. Please think about what you're doing with this software. Do you need to do this, do you need permission?

Comment: _"This has never happened before with any other URLs I have tried retrieve using this same method"_ — I seriously doubt that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't just echo someone's html and expect it to work. Assets (like scripts, images or stylesheets) won't load due to [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) violation unless the server has (mis)configured [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) rules. This is a protection layer in every modern browser that you won't overcome.

If you really want this to work you have to download each asset on the server side, store them locally and replace links in the code to your local copies. This is exactly how [web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)/online proxy software work.

Comment: This would be better as a comment

Comment: You can downvote my answers to other questions as much as you like. This is still not a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input.